# How to connect SQL Server database (table) with React JS project

Tags: php, reactjs, sql-server

I am new in React JS and I don't know how to connect to SQL Server database. The problem is that I have database configuration PHP file, `dbConfig.php` and I don't understand how to connect PHP files with React JS.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Tnx, Acknowledged!

Comment: ReactJS doesn't care what you use on backend. You start a server on some port , ReactJS makes api request to the port .

Comment: I suggest that you study a few things about backend development. E.g. read this guide on what you need to know in order to be competent at backend development: https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/modern-backend-developer-in-2018-6b3f7b5f8b9

Answer (score 1):

Php runs on the backend. React runs on the frontend. React does not (and should not) even touch the database.

What you need is to

a) create an API that can connect the frontend with the backend. Use something like the Slim Framework or Laravel.

b) write code that connects php to the database and then sends the result to the frontend through the API when a request is made